# Help me identify these parts of the sentence in the given question

Tags: parts-of-speech

This is the question that I am answering: name as many part of the sentences as you can;

> As she was crossing the street after she had picked up her dry cleaning from 'Britain's dry cleaning Wonder Shop', Claire wondered if Shane hadn't been in such a hurry that morning, he would have remembered their anniversary. Suddenly a red car came out of nowhere and she had to leap out of the way.

Would you be so kind and guide me, what is the role of:

'street': (direct object)? (crossing the street)

'Britain's dry cleaning Wonder Shop'?

'Morning'? (in such a hurry that morning)

'nowhere'? (out of nowhere)

'way'? (out of the way)

Comment: Where's it from? I'd want ' ... Claire wondered whether, if Shane ...'.

Comment: I don't know whether "Britain's Dry Cleaning Wonder Shop" is meant to be the  name of a fictitious company. If it is, it's rather long and cumbersome, but should be capitalised throughout.

Comment: I won't go into parts of speech, but in terms of meaning, "in such a hurry that morning" means she was in a hurry during the morning being spoken about; "out of nowhere" means the car suddenly appeared, as if by magic, and not from any obvious place; "out of the way" means moving from the path the car was following.

Comment: Thank you, I know the meaning of the phrases. I specifically need part of speeches.